# Replica forest in Error state. How to resolve and what could be the reason?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have the following error for one of my replica forests - 
`XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in merge of forest xyzzy-r1: SVC-UTF8SEQ: Invalid UTF-8 escape sequence: 0x99` making it unavailable.

Comment: You should write to MarkLogic support and get their help.

Comment: @hunterhacker yes, we did that.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the replica forest after taking the backup of the stands, and allowing it to self-replicate from primary forests helped to resolve the issue. 
The forest is back online, however the root cause of the issue to avoid future occurrence of this is yet to be known.